# Replacement of "in" with "to"

Tags: prepositions, perfect-constructions

Should I always replace **"in"** for **"to"** in Perfect Sentences after **"to be"** forms?

*I have been TO America\TO the party*

*He said he had been TO America\TO the party*

*When she comes he will have been TO America\TO the party*

*I knew when she came he would have been TO America\TO the party*

*If you had been TO America\TO the party, you would have been TO America\TO the party*

Comment: I'm confused because none of your examples use "in," and "in" would not be correct in any of them (unless "party" is used in the sense of a group of people rather than the celebratory/recreational event). Your title is also confusing due to the prepositions: usually we talk about "replacement **of** X **with** Y" (X becomes Y).

Comment: I meant I could have written all of it with "in" instead of "to" but I did it with "to". So, it's incorrect to say "I have been to the party"?

Comment: But there's nothing wrong with saying *I have been **in** America*. That's a true statement. (If you've been there.) In fact, to use one of your examples, you could say *I have been **in** America **at** the party.* So, the immediate answer to *should I always* is no. But it's not clear if that's what you *really* mean to ask.